# Refresh/update databound ComboBox immediately

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

I've made a windows form in which I can change names in my databasetable 'stations'. To select which station to change I've used a databound ComboBox which gets all stations from the database table.

Now when I change the name of a station I want to get it immediatly updated in my combobox without restarting the application.

Is there any way to do this or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504551/updating-a-databound-combobox) answer.  It implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx#Y0).