# How do you refresh a combo box item in-place?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

The ComboBox Items collection is an ObjectCollection, so of course you can store anything you want in there, but that means you don't get a Text property like you would with, say, a ListViewItem. The ComboBox displays the items by calling ToString() on each item, or using reflection if the DisplayMember property is set.

My ComboBox is in DropDownList mode. I have a situation where I want to refresh the item text of a single item in the list when it gets selected by the user. The problem is that the ComboBox doesn't re-query for the text at any time besides when it loads up, and I can't figure out how else to do what I want besides removing and re-adding the selected item like so:

```
PlantComboBoxItem selectedItem = cboPlants.SelectedItem as PlantComboBoxItem;

// ...

cboPlants.BeginUpdate();

int selectedIndex = cboPlants.SelectedIndex;
cboPlants.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
cboPlants.Items.Insert(selectedIndex, selectedItem);
cboPlants.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;

cboPlants.EndUpdate();
```

This code works fine, except for the fact that my SelectedIndex event ends up getting fired twice (once on the original user event, and then again when I re-set the property in this code). In this case, it's not a big deal that the event is fired twice, but it's inefficient, and I hate that. I could rig up a flag so it exits the event the second time, but that's hacking.

Is there a better way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, using Donut's suggestion.

In form class:

```
private BindingList<PlantComboBoxItem> _plantList;
```

In loading method:

```
_plantList = new BindingList<PlantComboBoxItem>(plantItems);
cboPlants.DataSource = _plantList;
```

In SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
int selectedIndex = cboPlants.SelectedIndex;
_plantList.ResetItem(selectedIndex);
```

Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, I wonder why no one thought to include something like a RefreshItem function on the ComboBox.

Comment: Noooooo... ResetItem() fires the SelectedIndexChanged method :(
Oh well, this is still cleaner that my original solution.

Comment: Do you need to call `ResetItem()`? The item in `cboPlants` should be changed if you just update it directly (I think?). You can access it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event with `_plantList[selectedIndex]`.

Comment: Yes, I do have to call ResetItem(). The control has no idea to refresh the item otherwise (I tried taking out that line and it didn't update the item when I changed it). The item does not get updated automatically even though the underlying data in the PlantComboBoxItem changed. I think the ResetItem() function must be internally implemented as what I was doing before -- manually removing and then adding the item again. Such a PITA.

Answer (score 11):

A dirty hack:

```
typeof(ComboBox).InvokeMember("RefreshItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, cboPlants, new object[] { });
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... could you use a [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433281/c-update-combobox-bound-to-generic-list/433299#433299)? That way, you could just modify the item in the underlying collection and have it reflected in the `ComboBox` without having to add or remove anything from the control.

You'd need to have a collection something like this, containing all your items for the `ComboBox`:

```
private BindingList<PlantComboBoxItem> plantComboBoxItems;
```

Then, at some point (like when the program is starting), bind it to the `ComboBox`:

```
cboPlants.DataSource = plantComboBoxItems;
```

Now, you can just modify the collection directly:

```
plantComboBoxItems[cboPlants.SelectedIndex].doWhateverYouWant();
```

And changes will be reflected in `cboPlants`. Is this what you're looking for?