# How to Bind List<> to ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code :

```
    public static List<string> MyTable = new List<string>();

dsView = new DataSet();

adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Fname FROM MEN", Conn);

adp.Fill(dsView, "MEN");

adp.Dispose();

foreach (DataRow R in dsView.Tables["MEN"].Rows)

GG.Add( R["Fname"].ToString());
```

how to Bind it to ComboBox ?

thank's in advance

Comment: What are you developing?  Windows app using WinForms?  Web app using Webforms or MVC?  WPF app?  Silverlight app? Mobile app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just set the ComboBox's DataSource equal to the List.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = MyTable;
```

If you use a System.ComponentModel.BindingList instead of a List then changes to the list will be sent to the ComboBox

Also should your last line:

```
GG.Add( R["Fname"].ToString());
```

be

```
MyTable.Add( R["Fname"].ToString());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440244/how-do-you-refresh-a-combo-box-item-in-place

Comment: thank's for the help,
what takes more memory, bind combobox to dataset or List<>   ?